# Silverlight with ado.net DataServices

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Does anyone have a good and clear article about why silverlight requires a callback everytime when I make a data access attempt?

Comment: Well, when i make a data query on the ado.net dataServices It requires a callback in to respond to the view request...I just want to know why silverlight has this nature and what are the benefits of this nature.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly straightforward and plain explanation of why MS chose to keep virtually all external requests asynchronus:

http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2008/07/omg-silverlight-asynchronous-is-evil.html